# How to config .htaccess files on of CakePHP new server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Whenever installed into a new hosting on website: [http://binhtichapvarem.com](http://binhtichapvarem.com/) with cpanel 11.5 troubled me about htacess file, usually will fail with error 500 and error font

I'm using a standard file format htacess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Please guidelines for selecting the standard .htaccess file cakephp 2.5,
Thank you

Comment: `.htaccess` files are interpreted by Apache, not by CakePHP. And HTTP 500 means you need to check your error logs.